# Why Add a new line at the end in XML when remove one whitespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, removing-whitespace

I have one file and I used this code to replace  `/>` with `/>` in line 6 but it add empty line at the end...Why? and how to solve it?

the file before edit the whitespace:

```
<xades:SignedProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2022-05-31T20:38:47Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                                    <ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">NjlhOTVmYzIzN2I0MjcxNGRjNDQ1N2EzM2I5NGNjNDUyZmQ5ZjExMDUwNGM2ODNjNDAxMTQ0ZDk1NDQ4OTRmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">2475382876776561391517206651645660279462721580</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
```

The XML file after remove the whitespace:

```
<xades:SignedProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2022-05-31T20:38:47Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                    <ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">NjlhOTVmYzIzN2I0MjcxNGRjNDQ1N2EzM2I5NGNjNDUyZmQ5ZjExMDUwNGM2ODNjNDAxMTQ0ZDk1NDQ4OTRmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">2475382876776561391517206651645660279462721580</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
```

my code is:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test.xml");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

> Blockquote

            if (lines[i].Contains(" />")) lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(" />", "/>");
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\test.xml", lines);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of *File.WriteAllLines*. It writes a collection of strings as lines, with each line terminated by an "end of line" character sequence, including the last string/line.

Instead of File.ReadAllLines/File.WriteAllLines, you could simply use File.ReadAllText/File.WriteAllText in your situation. As an additional bonus, unlike File.ReadAllLines/File.WriteAllLines, using the File.ReadAllText/File.WriteAllText combo will preserve the existing "end of line" character sequences regardless of them being Unix/Linux- or Windows-style line breaks no matter on which operating system your program runs.